# How can I reference a table/figure/section in another document?

Tags: cross-referencing, best-practices

I am writing documentation that includes three documents for different audiences:

1. Public
2. Staff
3. Developers

In the Developers document, I would like to reference a table or section in the Staff document using \ref{} or an analogous command.

Depending on the best way to do this, an alternative way to phrase this question might be "how can I write three interlinked but distinct documents?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/referencing-labels-from-other-files

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference another document in latex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/how-to-reference-another-document-in-latex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [xr](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/xr.html). I think that it does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you want. You might consider creating five documents: a preamble, postamble, and your other three, and then creating a fifth document that just does this:

```
\input{preamble.tex}
\input{public.tex}
\input{staff.tex}
\input{developers.tex}
\input{postable.tex}
```

You should be able to create a preamble that makes whatever customizations you want for each document in terms of layout, special numbering or whatever.

Then if you wanted to publish separately, it would just be a matter of stringin g the right `\include` statements together.

Also (adding this after some research) you may want to look at the [subdocs](http://ctan.org/pkg/subdocs) package.