# Split Journal Paper into Multiple Parts

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, document-classes, article, front-matter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reference a table/figure/section in another document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6363/how-can-i-reference-a-table-figure-section-in-another-document)

I am writing a journal paper that has grown to 30 pages long, so I would like to split it into two 15 page parts: part I and part II. I plan to submit both parts to the same journal at the same time, so I would like to be able to reference figures/tables/sections from part I in the text of part II, and vice versa. However, I need a separate bibliography and a separate frontmatter (title, authors, abstract, etc.) for each part.

I'm aware of the multibib package, but I believe that only fixes the separate bibliography problem.

Any ideas on how to do this? Multiple part journal papers seem to be fairly common, so I would think someone would have found a solution to this.

Comment: why not use something like PDFTK to split your final document into the desired sections? Do you require page numbering for each paper or what?

Comment: @Yossi: it seems so. Generally, if you think so, you may vote for closing as duplicate. If further users agree and vote for it, ok. If not, it won't be closed just accidentally.

Comment: @stefan: I don't have enough rep to vote to close...

Comment: @Yossi: ah, I wasn't aware of that. I've seen many good contributions by you, so I assumed that you've got such rights already. I guess, that will happen soon.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this question is very similar (possible duplicate?) of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6363/how-can-i-reference-a-table-figure-section-in-another-document/6368#6368). However, I'll give the answer that I gave there, here:

Take a look at [xr](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/xr.html), I think that it does what you are looking for.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of my problem from that perspective, but now I see that xr is probably just what I need.  Thanks!