# Reference to something in a different file, in a different directory?

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm working on a text that has to be split up in 4 parts, with each part containing it's own table of contents and it's own appendix. Four separate pdf's are needed.

The page numbers and section numbering has to be continued from one part to the other though, so eg. if `DEEL1` (in english: `PART1`) ends at page 10, `DEEL2` has to continue at page 11. Since I know the length of each document I have done this manually using `\setcounter{page}{10}` (same goes for sectioning, although I'm not sure of how to let the appendix sectioning work).

My directory is split up into folders for each part.

```
DELEN
├── DEEL1
├── DEEL2
├── DEEL3
└── DEEL4
```

Now I'd like to be able to reference something that isn't in that particular part. Eg.: if `\label{prt1:sec:section2}` is in part one, I would like to be able to use `\ref{prt1:sec:section2}` in parts two, three and four too.

Is this possible?

Comment: It might be possible with the `xr` or the more modern `zref-xr` package (`zref` bundle). In this case [How can I reference a table/figure/section in another document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6363/how-can-i-reference-a-table-figure-section-in-another-document) and [referencing labels from other files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/referencing-labels-from-other-files) would be related, but not that useful to you.

Comment: yes, I know about the ``xr`` package, but how would I go about pointing it to the correct directory? Can I just use: ``\externaldocument{../DEEL1/DEEL1}`` or would this be too simple?

Comment: I would say that is so simple, but accessing files in lower hierarchies (i.e. using the `..`) might not be allowed by the security settings.

Comment: @MartinScharrer It's forbidden to *write* in directories above or specified with an absolute path. Reading is usually allowed.

Comment: Ok the ``xr`` package works! Great. Perhaps you should make it into an answer (I won't accept egregs answer, because part of it didn't work for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## File `deel1.tex` in directory `deel1`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lastpage,xr,refcount,etoolbox}
\externaldocument{../deel2/deel2}
\externaldocument{../deel3/deel3}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\lastpage@putl@bel}{LastPage}{LastPage1}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First deel1}\label{first1}

\section{Second deel1}\label{second1}

\ref{first1} at page \pageref{first1}

\ref{second1} at page \pageref{second1}

\ref{first2} at page \pageref{first2}

\ref{second2} at page \pageref{second2}

\ref{first3} at page \pageref{first3}

\ref{second3} at page \pageref{second3}

\end{document}
```

## File `deel2.tex` in directory `deel2`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lastpage,xr,refcount,etoolbox}
\externaldocument{../deel1/deel1}
\externaldocument{../deel3/deel3}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\lastpage@putl@bel}{LastPage}{LastPage2}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{\getpagerefnumber{LastPage1}}
\stepcounter{page}
\tableofcontents

\section{First deel2}\label{first2}

\section{Second deel2}\label{second2}

\ref{first1} at page \pageref{first1}

\ref{second1} at page \pageref{second1}

\ref{first2} at page \pageref{first2}

\ref{second2} at page \pageref{second2}

\ref{first3} at page \pageref{first3}

\ref{second3} at page \pageref{second3}

\end{document}
```

## File `deel3.tex` in directory `deel3`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lastpage,xr,refcount,etoolbox}
\externaldocument{../deel1/deel1}
\externaldocument{../deel2/deel2}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\lastpage@putl@bel}{LastPage}{LastPage3}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{\getpagerefnumber{LastPage2}}
\stepcounter{page}
\tableofcontents

\section{First deel3}\label{first3}

\section{Second deel3}\label{second3}

\ref{first1} at page \pageref{first1}

\ref{second1} at page \pageref{second1}

\ref{first2} at page \pageref{first2}

\ref{second2} at page \pageref{second2}

\ref{first3} at page \pageref{first3}

\ref{second3} at page \pageref{second3}

\end{document}
```

## Notes

We have to patch `\lastpage@putl@bel` in order to have different labels in different documents (the "prefix" strategy provided by **xr** would be more cumbersome). The command to patch if **hyperref** is used is `\lastpage@putl@belhyper` (same code).

The same scheme will work for citations if the **xcite** package is used.

Comment: I'd like to thank you for your effort using the patched ``lastpage`` command. For some reason this didn't work though. Even so, you inspired me to create a simpler solution: put ``\label{LAST1}`` on the end of ``DEEL1.tex`` and use ``\setcounter{page}{\getpagerefnumber{LAST1}}`` in ``DEEL2.tex``. Not as elegant but at least I know what's happening.