# How to reference a label in a different file?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, cleveref

Is it possible to reference a label in another LaTeX document?

A very similar question [has already been asked and answered in this forum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29251/reference-to-something-in-a-different-file-in-a-different-directory). However, I'd like to use cleverefs and theorem lists which makes the problem more complex. Furthermore, the other question was asked 10 years ago; perhaps there are better ways to solve it now.

Consider the following LaTeX code which is copied from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336590/21685) and which I saved in a file named `test.tex`.

```
\documentclass[english]{amsart}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}  % for '\newlist' and '\setlist' macros
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
%%\usepackage{amsthm}  % is loaded automatically by amsart document class
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\crefname{thm}{Thm.}{Thms.} % singular and plural forms of label

\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\crefname{cor}{Cor.}{Cors.} % singular and plural forms of label

\newlist{enumthm}{enumerate}{1} % set up a dedicated enumeration env.
\setlist[enumthm]{label=\upshape(\alph*),ref=\upshape\thethm(\alph*)}
\crefalias{enumthmi}{thm} % alias 'enumthmi' counter to 'thm'

\newlist{enumcor}{enumerate}{1} % set up a second dedicated enumeration env.
\setlist[enumcor]{label=\upshape(\alph*),ref=\upshape\thecor(\alph*)}
\crefalias{enumcori}{cor} % alias 'enumcori' counter to 'cor'

\makeatletter
\newcounter{subcreftmpcnt} %
\newcommand\alphsubformat[1]{(\alph{#1})} %adapt ....
\newcommand\subcref[2][\alphsubformat]{%
\ifcsname r@#2@cref\endcsname
  \cref@getcounter {#2}{\mylabel}%
  \setcounter{subcreftmpcnt}{\mylabel}%
  \alphsubformat{subcreftmpcnt}%
 \else ?? \fi}   
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example

\begin{thm}\label{Thm:One}
The following properties hold:
\begin{enumthm}
    \item\label{Thm:One:1} \(1>0\)
    \item\label{Thm:One:2} \(0<1\)
\end{enumthm}
\end{thm}

\begin{cor}\label{Thm:Two}
The following properties hold as well:
\begin{enumcor}
    \item\label{Thm:Two:1} \(2>1\)
    \item\label{Thm:Two:2} \(1<2\)
\end{enumcor}
\begin{proof}
\subcref{Thm:Two:1} follows from \ref{Thm:One:1} by adding 1 on both sides. Similarly,  \subcref{Thm:Two:2}  follows from \cref{Thm:One:2}.
\end{proof}
\end{cor}

\end{document}
```

I ran `lualatex test` twice, and both executions ended successfully. The typeset output was:

[image: Theorem sublists]

Now consider the following LaTeX code that I saved in a file named `test2.tex` and which is loosely modeled on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41547/21685) answer:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[A-]{test}[test.pdf]
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\ref{A-Thm:Two:1} follows from \ref{A-Thm:One:1} by adding 1 on both sides. Similarly,  \ref{A-Thm:Two:2}  follows from \ref{A-Thm:One:2}.
\end{document}
```

When I run `lualatex test2`, the execution ends successfully, and the typeset output is:

[image: Cross referencing labels across files.]

**Questions**

Is there a way to get the last reference in the output from `test2.tex` to typeset as *Thm. 1.1.(b)* rather than *1.1(b)*, in a similar manner to the way `test.tex` works?

Comment: xr-hyper should work I expect. If it doesn't, then make a small example and show the error you get

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I've edited my question per your comment.

Comment: your example shows an error only vaguely connected to your question. You have used a command `\subcref` that you have not defined.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: OK. I've changed `\subcref` to `\ref` and it seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: However, is there a way to get the output from `test2.tex` to typeset as *Thm. 1.1.(b)* rather than as *1.1(b)*, just like the output from `test.tex`?

Comment: is that what your subcref command was doing? then use that (but you need its definition in that case)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It's not `\subcref` its' `\cref`, and it's supposed to be available in package `cleveref`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Oh, OK. I've got it. Thanks. Should I post an answer or will you?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I've posted an answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Just one more thing, please. Is it possible to automatically add a suffix to those references that point to another file, in order not to confuse them with references that point inside the same file? In other words, when I reference a label in another file, I'd like the output to be, say, *test:1.1(b)* or *1.1(b) (test.pdf)* rather than simply *1.1(b)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the code in `test2.tex` by the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[A-]{test}[test.pdf]
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{thm}{Thm.}{Thms.} % singular and plural forms of label
\begin{document}
\ref{A-Thm:Two:1} follows from \ref{A-Thm:One:1} by adding 1 on both sides. Similarly,  \ref{A-Thm:Two:2}  follows from \cref{A-Thm:One:2}.
\end{document}
```

and ran `lualatex test2` twice. The executions terminated successfully, and the typeset output was as desired:

[image: Using cleverefs in tandem with xr-hyperref to reference labels in a different file]