# Appendices in separate file (Cross Referencing)

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices

I have a big `report` with `appendices`. Now I would like to put my `appendices` in a separate file. That's no problem at all. But I refer to my `appendices` in my main file. What would be the easiest way to refer to my `appendices` in my main file, while the `appendices` themselves are separate?

Right now I have my `appendices` both in my main file and a separate `appendices` file and made sure the page numbering is the same. But now I have my `appendices` in my main file while I dont need them there.

Is there some easier way to do this?

Short version: is there some easy way to crossrefer to another latex file?

Comment: User the [`xr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xr) package (or `xr-hyper`), have a look at [How to reference another document in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/how-to-reference-another-document-in-latex). If the answer there can already help you, we could close this question as a duplicate with link to that answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [\ref'erencing \label's from other files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/referencing-labels-from-other-files)

Comment: Reading both the links u gave me, gimme a minute to see if that covers my question.

Comment: I took a look at the `xr` and `xr-hyper` packages. There aint too much documentation on it. They seem to assume both latex files are in the same folder. Would it be possible also to refer to a file in a complete different folder?

Comment: Maybe what you want to do is better served with `\include`/`\includeonly`.  See [When should I use \input vs \include ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/2693) for more information on this.

Comment: @Alan Munn how could i solve my problem/question using `\include` and `\includeonly` then?

Comment: @Elmer the idea is that you keep your appendices as separate files, but you use `\include` to include them in your source. This keeps your source documents manageable, but the whole document behaves as a single document from the point of view of cross-references.

Comment: @Alan Munn I already do so, i have 1 main file, and use `\include` to include them in my mainfile. But with my seperate appendices, i have 2 "mainfiles".

Comment: @Elmer Then I guess I don't understand your problem anymore. Suppose I have a main.tex plus chap1.tex, chap2.tex, app1.tex, app2.tex etc. and use `\include` to include the chapters.  How is that the same as having more than one main file?

Comment: @Alan Munn Its not the same. I have 2 main files. I use main1 to indlude my `chapters`. Main2 is used to include my `appendices`. 

now the question is, what the easiest way is, to refer to my `appendices` in main1.

hope u understand what i mean now. Excuse my english.

Comment: @Elmer: I believe Alan is suggesting that you keep the references in the same document, but in a file included with `\include`. Then you can use `\includeonly` to produce separate PDFs, one without references and one that is only references.

Comment: @Elmer: Er, appendices, not references. Not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example with the [refstyle](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/refstyle/) and `xr` packages (you need some work to get the TOC right). Create your main file, say `Main.tex`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nokeyprefix]{refstyle}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \externaldocument[A-]{App-A}
    \externaldocument[B-]{App-B}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\begin{equation}
  E = m c^2
  \label{eq:Einst}
\end{equation}
In \eqref[s]{eq:Einst} and \eqref*[xr=A-, vref]{eq:e} ...
\end{document}
```

Then create the Appendix, say `App-A.tex`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nokeyprefix]{refstyle}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
  \externaldocument[Main-]{Main}

\begin{document}
\appendix
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\setcounter{page}{50}
\chapter{First}
\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{e}^{i\pi}-1 = 0
  \label{eq:e}
\end{equation}
In \eqref[s,xr=Main-,vref]{eq:Einst} and \eqref*{eq:e} ...
\end{document}
```

Compile both then the hyperlinks will be active and you can jump between the pdf files