# Using \include(only) to produce 2 pdf-s: text and references

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, include, multiple-files

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16006/appendices-in-separate-file-cross-referencing#comment29972_16006) is what I want to do:

> you keep the references in the same document, but in a file included
>   with \include. Then you can use \includeonly to produce separate PDFs,
>   one without references and one that is only references.

But how?

Note: "references" as a bibliography, not cross-references

Comment: Please explain the question a bit more. Are references literally references as in a bibliography, or just cross-references to, say, equations?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would interpret the suggestion in the linked question.

Put everything but the bibliography in one (or more) file(s), and the bibliography material in a separate file, and pull all of them in with `\include`s.  Process the whole job as many times as necessary, until all cross-references are resolved.

When there are no more errors (or warnings), use `\includeonly` to process the main text file(s) separately.  All the existing `.aux` files will be read in, so the result should be the same as the full run, except that the bibliography won't be at the end.  Rename that `.pdf` file so it won't be lost.

Now, change the `\includeonly` to pull in only the bibliography.  Again, all existing `.aux` files will be read in, although they're probably not needed.  The resulting `.pdf` file will contain only the bibliography.  Rename *that* `.pdf` file to a name different from the main text `.pdf`.

Now you have two separate `.pdf` files, each with different content, as you have requested.