# How to reference sections, equations, and figures in a separate document (e.g., supplemental information)?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I have a main document (manuscript) and a supplemental document.

I wonder if there is a way that I can "link" the two (make them recognize each other) so that section, equation, and figure references across documents are recognized?

Comment: Look at [Does hyperref work between two files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/does-hyperref-work-between-two-files/41547#41547)

Comment: possible duplicate [how-to-reference-another-document-in-latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/how-to-reference-another-document-in-latex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `xr` package is probably what you need.

Comment: And also `xr-hyper` if `hyperref` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xr` package with the following setup in the header of both files

`\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[]{name_of_other_file_without_extension}`

You can then just use regular `\ref{fig:label name}` like you would in the same document.

Placing this header info at the bottom on the header will likely reduce package conflicts regarding `hyperref`.

[source](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-extref.html) for more reading.